# How to register and access all services implementing a generic interface?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, generics, dependency-injection

The generic interface:

```cs
public interface IEntityFactory<T>
{
    public Task<IEnumerable<T>> Sample();
}
```

The services:

```cs
public class RegionFactory : IEntityFactory<Region>
{
    public async Task<IEnumerable<Region>> Sample()
    {
        // return list of Regions.
    }
}

public class UserFactory : IEntityFactory<User>
{
    public async Task<IEnumerable<User>> Sample()
    {
        // return list of Users.
    }
}
```

How do I register these services in such a way that I can then access all of them as an enumerable, and call the `Sample` method on each. It's okay if the return type of `Sample` is something non-specific like `Task<IEnumerable<object>>`.

I've tried many combinations of registration and access, but I can't seem to find a working solution.

Comment: And what are you doing with the list of returned `System.Object` instances. There's nothing much to call without doing reflection on them. You might want to describe what it is you like to achieve; that might lead to answers that are more useful to you.

Comment: The `Sample` methods have the side-effect of persisting "sample" data, similar to "seeding", so the return value is only needed when a factory is injected into another factory. When the application is started with a specific CLI argument, the factories will be registered, accessed, and have their `Sample` method invoked to load sample data into the database. I hope that makes sense.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This doesn't work. You have to create a new non-generic interface that has a non-generic method like:

```
public interface IEntityFactory
{
    public Task<System.Collections.IEnumerable> Sample();
}
```

Now all your factories have to implement this interface also and you can consume it in your service with `IEnumerable<IEntityFactory>`.

Depending on your structure you could additionally create a generic abstract base class that implements both interfaces and needs only an implementation of the generic part and does the non-generic by herself:

```
public abstract class EntityFactoryBase<T> : IEntityFactory<T>, IEntityFactory
{
    public abstract Task<IEnumerable<T>> Sample();

    async Task<System.Collections.IEnumerable> IEntityFactory.Sample()
    {
        return await Sample();
    }
}
```

By this approach your factories derive from the base class and have only to implement the one interface method as before, but in your receiving services you can also consume the non-generic interface.

Comment: This appears to work. I've registered the factories as both `IEntityFactory` _and_ `IEntityFactory<T>`, the former for accessing all factories, and the latter for accessing specific factories (f.e. within another factory), using forwarding like this (https://andrewlock.net/how-to-register-a-service-with-multiple-interfaces-for-in-asp-net-core-di/#2-implement-forwarding-using-factory-methods). Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

With the given design, you will have to iterate all `IEntityFactory<T>` implementations, and resolve them from the container. For instance:

```cs
Type[] factoryTypes = new[]
{
    typeof(IEntityFactory<Region>), typeof(IEntityFactory<User>)
}

IServiceProvider sp = ...

using (var scope = sp.CreateScope())
{
    object[] factories =
        factoryTypes.Select(scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService)
        .ToArray();

    foreach (dynamic factory in factories)
    {
        dynamic _ = factory.Sample();
    }
}
```

This assumes the factories are registered by their interface:

```cs
services.AddTransient<IEntityFactory<Region>, RegionFactory>();
services.AddTransient<IEntityFactory<User>, UserFactory>();
// etc
```

This last code snippet also assumes you are using MS.DI, and not another DI Container.

Or optionally, when you have access to the `IServiceCollection`, you can query the service collection for factories:

```cs
IServiceCollection services = ...

Type[] factoryTypes = (
    from d in services
    where d.ServiceType.IsGenericType
    where d.ServiceType.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(IEntityFactory<>)
    select d.ServiceType)
    .ToArray();
    
// The rest stays the same.
```